# How do you form data to make an array of n features and n samples in scikit learn decision tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to scikit learn, and I am attempting to train a classifier to predict what type of car is most likely given a specific input:

My data looks like this:

18.0    8    307.0       130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1  chevrolet

15.0   8   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70  1     buick

18.0   8   318.0      150.0      3436.      11.0   70  1     plymouth

17.0   8   302.0      140.0      3449.      10.5   70  1     ford torino

15.0   8   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70  1     ford galaxie 500

14.0   8   454.0      220.0      4354.       9.0   70  1     chevrolet impala

14.0   8   440.0      215.0      4312.       8.5   70  1     plymouth fury iii

where each column of data is a specific feature of the car: mpg, cylinders, horsepower, acceleration, etc.

I am representing the cars in a numerical form:

```
    cars = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2]
```

where 0 = chevy, 1 = buick, etc.

Here is my code for the program:

```
    data = np.loadtxt("my_data")

    mpg = data[:,0]
    cylinders = data[:,1]
    displacement = data[:,2]
    horsepower = data[:,3]
    weight = data[:,4]
    acceleration = data[:,5]
    modelyear = data[:,6]
    origin = data[:,7]


    X = [mpg, cylinders, displacement, horsepower, weight, 
    acceleration,   acceleration, modelyear, origin]

    car_type = [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(X, car_type)
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "scikitlearn_practice.py", line 21, in <module>
   clf.fit(X, car_type)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py",   
   line 739, in fit
   X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 
   240, in fit
   "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
   ValueError: Number of labels=17 does not match number of samples=8
```

How do I fix this error so that the labels match the number of samples?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have a problem here at the X declaration. As stated in the documentation, X must be of shape [n_samples, n_features], whereas in your code, what you have is an array of shape [n_features, n_samples], i.e [[18.0,15.0,...,14.0], [8,8,...,8],...,[1,1,...,1]].

What you need is actually an array where each row describes one sample, i.e [[18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,1],...,[14.0,8,440.0,215.0,4312.,8.5,70,1]]. This is already what you have in your **data** array.

Using this information, you can then rewrite the code :

```
X = np.loadtxt("my_data")

car_type = [1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, car_type)
```

However, executing this code still leads to an error,
    `Number of labels=17 does not match number of samples=7`

This is because your label array contains 17 labels (for 17 corresponding samples), whereas your samples array only contains 7 samples (i.e, 7 cars described by their features).

The **car_type** array should contain as many labels as samples you have in your *X* array, so the error lies in your data.

I don't know what **car_types** is supposed to be, but your **cars** array contains 7 samples and seems to correspond to the data you have in my_data, so maybe what you are trying to do is :

```
X = np.loadtxt("my_data")
cars = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2] 
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, cars)
```

Doing so, I was able to fit the model with your data.
Hope it helped.